# $resource Callback not Being Invoked Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angular-resource

I have a method which makes a call to Angular's $resource.  I am trying to test the return value of this method. This method should be simple enough to test.

**Method Code**

```
getCountries(): returnTypeObject {
        var countries = this.$resource(
            this.apiEndpoint.baseUrl,
            {
                'get': {
                    method: 'GET', isArray: false
                }
            });
        return countries;
    }
```

**Unit Test**

```
describe('module', (): void => {

    beforeEach((): void => {
        angular.mock.module('ngResource');
    });

    describe('getCountries...', (): void => {

        it("should...", inject(
            ['Builder', (Builder: IBuilder): void => {
                Builder.getCountries().get(
                    (value: any) => {
                        console.log(value);
                    }, (error: any) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }]));
    });

});
```

Now in the above code when I run my test the none of the callbacks ever get called.  Neither "value" nor "error" ever get printed.  I've been looking for a solution for quite a while now but haven't been able to find anything.

Keep in mind that I do not want to mock $resource, instead I want to test what is returned by getCountries().get() and then I want to use the callbacks to test the return value.

Comment: $resource is async. var countries in your code is just deffered, so your variant: Builder.getCountries().get().then(function(yourRealResponse){ console.log(yourRealResponse); }).catch(function(yourError){});

Comment: Thanks @KoIIIeY   Could there be any reason why the object returned by getCountries is undefined?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. Theoretically getCountries should return resource object.

Comment: I think my problem is that I should be testing this asynchronously... I have made another post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319907/async-callback-was-not-invoked-within-timeout-specified)